# JSF telephone numbers regular expression

Tags: regex, validation, jsf

I'm using primefaces of JSF, I'm doing a regular expression checking for the input of phone number, accepted values are:

909888
+90877845

here's my code

```
<p:inputText validatorMessage="invalid value">
   <f:validateRegex pattern="^[+]?[0-9]+$" />
</p:inputText>
```

My problem is that the expression does not pass the empty values, as the field is not required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are really close, you need to surround the entire match in a `()?`.  This means the regex will need to match the entire inside 1 or 0 times.  A blank string will validate against the 0, and your `+####` will validate on the time where that pattern is matched once.

`^([+]?[\d]+)?$` should work, it also makes it a little easier to read since `\d` means any digit, but `0-9` should work fine.  I did some testing with your values and the new addition [here](http://rubular.com/r/zdCxIzLyWy).

Also, if there is a specific count of numbers that can be in range (i.e. valid if the number is between 6 and 8 in length) you can modify the `[\d]+` to `[\d]{x,y}` where `x` and `y` are your minimum/maximum length requirements.

Comment: @Smartdog fixed up the answer and updated the example tests I did to be a little bit more robust.  The new changes should work.

Comment: That's very strange .. I tried you answer before and it didn't work .. glad it did finally, thank you